# How can I combine multiple paths in an SVG file into a single path using Java

Tags: java, svg, javafx, batik

I am trying to build a road system network using paths on my svg. This is a sample of my path

```
<path id="L4H" style="fill:none;stroke-width:0.75;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:3;" d="M 0.000668985 396.649337 L 96.301547 396.649337 " transform="matrix(0.999999,0,0,0.997983,146.307925,-282.755491)"/>
<path id="L2" style="fill:none;stroke-width:0.75;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:3;" d="M -0.0000537782 396.648548 L 94.179729 396.648548 " transform="matrix(0.999999,0,0,0.997983,18.375054,-188.44611)"/>
<path id="L1" style="fill:none;stroke-width:0.75;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:3;" d="M -0.0000537782 396.65004 L 94.179729 396.65004 " transform="matrix(0.999999,0,0,0.997983,18.375054,-210.900725)"/>
<path id="L2toL4" style="fill:none;stroke-width:0.75;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:3;" d="M -0.00207423 396.650411 L 47.728842 396.64925 " transform="matrix(0.707106,-0.70568,0.707106,0.70568,-167.917758,-72.503655)"/>
<path id="L4V" style="fill:none;stroke-width:0.75;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:3;" d="M 0.00121335 396.648763 L 60.748749 396.648763 " transform="matrix(0.000000000000000061,-0.997983,0.999999,0.000000000000000061,-250.343675,173.723867)"/>
<path id="L3toL1" style="fill:none;stroke-width:0.75;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:3;" d="M -0.000472636 396.64847 L 16.722096 396.65008 " transform="matrix(0.672672,-0.738447,0.739939,0.671316,-180.940745,-81.32762)"/>
```

This path has various vertexes and edges that connect the road network (I use the graph as my data structure). My plan is to call a start vertex to say `L4H` and end vertex `L1`, get the shortest pathh and from the result, I would use Java to get the path. The problem is that I can do that for one path

```
Element element = doc.getElementById("L14");
            pathData = element.getAttributeNode("d").getValue();
            transformMatrix = element.getAttributeNode("transform").getValue();
parser.parse(pathData);

        path = handler.getPath();
        path.getElements().forEach(System.out::println);

        String tempTransformMatrix1 = transformMatrix.replace("matrix(", "");
        String tempTransformMatrix2 = tempTransformMatrix1.replace(")", "");

        var a = tempTransformMatrix2.split(",");
        path.getTransforms()
                .add(Transform.affine(w, e, e,
                        e,f, s));
        path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
```

I would like to combine all paths for a route into an individual path before playing the transition. (I use batik for the SVG dom parsing)

Comment: Depending on the transforms it's just not possible to display all the svg paths in a single JavaFX `Path`: a javafx `Path` is not able to include multiple scalings and therefore you must use different paths for the graphical representation. You could however get a representation of the paths from the svg that does not involve path thickness. SVG without any constraints seems to be a weird way to store data like this: Usually you'd store untransformed paths and some details like road type and leave the graphical representation to the program using the data...

Comment: @fabian. I am not trying to show all the paths on the road map. Just only paths for an individual route excluding all other paths.